# Is there a convenient method to pull files from a server in an SSH session?

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, alias

I often SSH into a cluster node for work and after processing want to pull several results back to my local machine for analysis. Typically, to do this I use a local shell to scp from the server, but this requires a lot of path manipulation. I'd prefer to use a syntax like interactive FTP and just 'pull' files from the server to my local pwd.

Another possible solution might be to have some way to automatically set up my client computer as an ssh alias so that something like

```
scp results home:~/results
```

would work as expected.

Is there any obscure SSH trick that'll do this for me?

---

Working from **grawity**'s answer, a complete solution in config files is something like

local .ssh/config:

```
Host ex
    HostName ssh.example.com
    RemoteForward 10101 localhost:22
```

ssh.example.com .ssh/config:

```
Host home
    HostName localhost
    Port 10101
```

which lets me do commands exactly like

```
scp results home:
```

transferring the file results to my home machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'd prefer to use a syntax like interactive FTP and just 'pull' files from the server to my local pwd.

Use `sftp`.

(Hint: If you cannot or do not want to open a new window, you can suspend the SSH connection by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, transfer your files, and resume SSH with `fg`.)

> Another possible solution might be to have some way to automatically set up my client computer as an ssh alias

There are a few ways.

- Static alias for `ssh` and `scp` – add this to your `~/.ssh/config`:

  ```
  Host home
      # If you don't have a domain name, check out DynDNS...
      # ...or just use your IP address.
      Hostname homepc.somedomain.tld

      # If necessary, uncomment:
      #User john
      #Port 1234
  ```

  Use:

  ```
  scp foo home:
  ```

  (If you don't provide a path after `:`, the file will go to your home directory.)
- Use the `SSH_CLIENT` environment variable.

  ```
  export client=${SSH_CLIENT%% *}
  if [[ $client == *:* ]]; then
      client="[$client]"
  fi
  ```

  Put that in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` or wherever you want, then use `$client` when you need your own address.

  ```
  scp foo "$client:"
  ```
- Mix both.

  `~/.ssh/config`:

  ```
  Host client
      ProxyCommand ~/bin/reverse-connect %p
  ```

  `~/bin/reverse-connect`:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  if [[ $SSH_CLIENT ]]; then
      client=${SSH_CLIENT%% *}
  else
      echo "I don't know your address." >&2
      exit 1
  fi
  if [[ $client == *:* ]]; then
      client="[$client]"
  fi

  port=${1:-22}

  exec socat - "tcp:$client:$port"
  ```

  Use:

  ```
  scp foo client:
  ```

Comment: SSH_CLIENT is almost perfect! What about if I'm behind a router, though? It's common since I'm connecting from a laptop. I had been imagining some sort of reverse ssh tunneling scheme, but I don't know how to set that up.

Comment: @tel: Method 1, port forwarding: Pick any port and forward it to port 22/tcp on your computer. Tell the same port to `scp` when copying files.

Comment: @tel: Method 2, "reverse forwarding" with SSH: `ssh -R 2345:localhost:22` will make your computer reachable as `localhost` port `2345` from the remote server.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried sshfs ?
It's easy as

```
> sshfs hostname: mountpoint
```

and

```
fusermount -u mountpoint
```

and then you can use all the classic and basic file manipulation commands.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS

http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

Comment: `sshfs` is *fantastic*. Much more usable than `sftp` and `gftp`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `scp` from your local host.  Use a command like `scp server:file .`.

Your other options include `sftp` and `sshfs` as already noted.

For all of these I would use authorized keys.  It is more secure to password protect your key.  I use ssh-agent to serve the keys to ssh as needed.  The command ssh-add will prompt you for your key's password and load the key into ssh-agent.